# 'Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.' on mvn command

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu

when I run the command

> mvn version

in ubuntu I get the following error.

> Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
>     We cannot execute /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java

My java version is

> java version "1.8.0_91" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
>   1.8.0_91-b14) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)

And I run

> sudo nano /etc/environment

command and set java home and maven  as

> JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre"
>   M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.2.5
>   MAVEN_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.2.5
>   M2=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.2.5/bin

And my path variable is -

> /usr/share/maven3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre:/home/hduser/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/local/hadoop/bin:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin:/usr/local/hadoop/bin:/usr/lib/sqoop/bin:/home/hduser/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin

And run command

> sudo nano ~/.bashrc

and set these at the end

> JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
>   PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin export JAVA_HOME export JRE_HOME
>   export PATH export M2_HOME=/usr/share/maven3 export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
>   export PATH=$M2:$PATH

I have install java 8 and remove java 7 and then run the mvn command and I am getting this error. I am curious to know why it is showing java 7 rather then java 8 and Please also suggest me some solution.
Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

My bashrc  is -

```
    # ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
    # see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
    # for examples

    # If not running interactively, don't do anything
    case $- in
        *i*) ;;
          *) return;;
    esac

    # don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
    # See bash(1) for more options
    HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

    # append to the history file, don't overwrite it
    shopt -s histappend

    # for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
    HISTSIZE=1000

    # ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
    # see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
    # for examples

    # If not running interactively, don't do anything
    case $- in
        *i*) ;;
          *) return;;
    esac

    # don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
    # See bash(1) for more options
    HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

    # append to the history file, don't overwrite it
    shopt -s histappend

    # for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
    HISTSIZE=1000
    HISTFILESIZE=2000

    # check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
    # update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
        # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
        # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
        # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
        color_prompt=yes
    else
        color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'

alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*al$

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then

 . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
#=======================================
# Added by TKS to conexport PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
figure HDFS
#=======================================
#HADOOP VARIABLES START
export HADOOP_INSTALL=/usr/local/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib"
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
#export SQOOP_HOME=/usr/local/sqoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
#export PATH=$PATH:$SQOOP_HOME/bin
export SQOOP_HOME=/usr/lib/sqoop
#HADOOP VARIABLES END
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export PATH
export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.2.5
export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
export PATH=$M2:$PATH
```

Comment: What output does `echo $JAVA_HOME` show? Does it point to the right place? If not, there's something else that's setting your `JAVA_HOME`.

Comment: Did you restart the box after java 8 upgrade?

Comment: 'echo $JAVA_HOME' output is  '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre' and yes it shows correct location of my java

Comment: Remove all things like `M2_HOME` and `M2`not need etc. Only put the folder where maven is installed (/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.2.5/bin` in your PATH and of course set JAVA_HOME correctly. Nothing more.

Comment: Yes I also restart my system after all the changes made

Comment: Reinstall maven?? I know - it is brutal but sometimes ...

Comment: I tried this @ khmarbaise but it is not working. And what you means by correct java_home path. can you explain?

Comment: Your JAVA_HOME Points to a jre. I think it must Point to a JDK

Answer (score 2):

I think your `JAVA_HOME` is supposed to be JDK and not JRE since Maven compile the Java code and there's no Java compiler (javac) in the JRE.

Comment: Can you try the following command `source ~/.bashrc` and try again `mvn -version` ?

Comment: Ok. Can you try `. ~/.bashrc` instead ? It's the same command. Be careful not to forget the first `.`at the begining.

Comment: Ok. You definitely have an issue in your `.bashrc`. Could you please provide it in your request ?

Comment: how can I provide it in my request

Comment: You can update your request and copy/paste the content of your `.bashrc`. Also be careful, if you have confidential informations in it such as logins, passwords, servers names, etc...

Comment: In your `.bashrc`, you have `figure HDFS`. It seems the command `figure` is not found in your `PATH`. You should add the directory of this command into your `PATH`.

Comment: Fix it. Figure HDFS is commented section after comment it 'figure: command not found' error is resolved. But I still get Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly. We cannot execute /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java error when run mvn command

Comment: Can you execute `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -version` and share the result ?

Comment: bash: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory

Comment: This is the problem. Based on your .bashrc, your `JAVA_HOME` should be `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle` and not `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64`. Can you execute export `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle` and try again `mvn -version` ?

Comment: check my bash file in above edits. I am used the same export command and java version as you metioned. But it still show error for java 7

Comment: Did you execute the commands ? Also could you confirm you're using `bash` interpreter (and not `ksh` or `sh`) ?

Comment: Yes I excute the command ot show me error. And I am using bash interpreter I confirmed this by run  echo "$SHELL" command

Answer (score 0):

The following should be enough :

**JAVA_HOME**=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

**M2_HOME**=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.2.5

**PATH**=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

**PATH**=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin

Remove other `M2` or `MAVEN_HOME` variables that you have declared.